# How to understand `authentication and authorization permissions`?

Tags: meaning

When I read this [toturial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6Doj2LOIlo):

in the `0:11/10.07` point, the author says:

> authentication and authorization permissions with Django ...

I want to know does he means the `authentication permissions and authorization permissions` or `authentication and authorization permissions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of sentences you provided mean the same thing: permission to authenticate and authorize.

Answer (score 2):

Both are technical phrases in IT.

**Authentication** means *identification* of something or someone, acquiring and assuring the identity of something. It's like asking for a password, a biometric attribute or a statement by two witnesses.

**Authorisation** means *granting access* for something to a (usually)  identified entity. It can be a permission for a person to access a building, a firewall entry letting a machine access a service or a right for an identified account to post blog entries.

Comment: I know this means. I just want to know whether `authentication and authorization permissions` means `authentication permissions and authorization permissions`.

Comment: Okay. Yes, it does.